# Im trying to ping the user that used the command but it doesnt work. Discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def shift(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ER:LC Server Shift", description="server name shift Please go onto your staff team and assist people.", inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send {message.author.mention}
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Add code that you've tried, any documentation you've relied on, that looks like you've tried to fix a problem and failed. Your question is not clear

Comment: Why are you using `{ }` brackets after your `ctx.channel.send` function? You should instead be using `( )` like you have done with your `ctx.send`, unless you're trying to use [an f-string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `( )` at the line `await ctx.channel.send`. If you want to mention the author and send it as a message, you need to have brackets `{ }` in that line, since `message.author.mention` inside `( )` is an f-string.

```py
@client.command()
async def shift(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ER:LC Server Shift", description="server name shift Please go onto your staff team and assist people.", inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```